# How do I change one Item Entity into another/different entity using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, what I have for my command so far is:

```
/execute @e[type=Item] {id:"minecraft:double_plant"} ~ ~ ~ summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{Count:1, id:17}}
```

The point of this command is to summon `minecraft:log` at the `minecraft:double_plant` entities. Progress is not really coming along so well though. I can summon a log at an item but I can't specify which specific item i want to summon it at. This is where I am having trouble.

Another command I used is this one:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~-1 ~ ~-1 ~1 ~10 ~1 double_plant 0 destroy log
```

Now, this one works, kinda. It will just infinitely summons minecraft:double_plant. It will how ever destroy the blocks in the area given and drop the Item form, but will not only break minecraft:log. It will break every block.

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated! I am running all the commands on a clock.

Answer (score 2):

/execute's syntax:

```
/execute <target> X Y Z <command>
/execute <target> X Y Z detect X Y Z <block> <Damage> <command>
```

There is no section for dataTags. You must use a command that supports dataTags to apply a label based on NBT data first, such as `/scoreboard`, and then target the entity based on that label.

You should also **not** be using numerical IDs, since they are deprecated in 1.8 NBT data (and unusable in most command syntax) and no longer works at all in 1.9.

### Item replacement

Instead of summoning a new item to 'replace' another item, you can use /entitydata to change the ID of the already-existing item.

**Prerequisites:**

An objective to label the item entity as being a double plant.

```
/scoreboard objectives add DoublePlant dummy
```

**Clock commands:**

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. First, assign a score to items that are double plants.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] DoublePlant 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:double_plant"}}
   ```
2. Change the ID of the item using /entitydata.

   ```
   /entitydata @e[type=Item,score_DoublePlant_min=1] {Item:{id:"minecraft:log"}}
   ```
3. Reset the score of the item.

   ```
   /scoreboard players reset @e[type=Item,score_DoublePlant_min=1] DoublePlant
   ```

### Entity replacement

As per title, if you intend to replace an item entity with a non-item entity, you will need to use /execute like you've done, but with the proper label.

**Prerequisites:**

An objective to label the item entity as being a double plant.

```
/scoreboard objectives add DoublePlant dummy
```

**Clock commands:**

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. First, assign a score to items that are double plants.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] DoublePlant 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:double_plant"}}
   ```
2. Summon a new entity at double plant items.

   ```
   /execute @e[type=Item,score_DoublePlant_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Creeper
   ```
3. Kill the item entity to prevent constant summoning of creepers (which will also clear its scoreboard.dat record automatically).

   ```
   /kill @e[type=Item,score_DoublePlant_min=1]
   ```

### 1.9 changes

Instead of using scoreboard objectives, you can use the new "tags" feature to apply a label directly onto the entity. The benefit is a less-bloated scoreboard.dat (since scoreboard.dat is not involved at all) and easier prevention of constant command activation.

1. Assign a tag to items that are double plants.

   ```
   /scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item,tag=!DoublePlant] add DoublePlant {Item:{id:"minecraft:double_plant"}}
   ```
2. Change the item's ID using /entitydata while also removing all tags from the item at the same time to prevent constant activation.

   ```
   /entitydata @e[type=Item,tag=DoublePlant] {Item:{id:"minecraft:log"},Tags:[]}
   ```